# Chrome bug: border-radius + border with same color as background -> artifacts

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Sorry for the obtuse title; [here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KPAVU/).

Basically, I've got a div inside of another one. The big one has a light blue background, and the little one has a darker blue background.
I want to give the smaller one a border on hover, so I start it with the same size border but the same color as the background (so that it doesn't move around when the border is added).

This border that is the same color as the background artifacts when there's a border radius. Take a look at Chrome:
[image]

But Safari is fine:
[image]

Is this a known bug? Can I submit a report?
And more importantly, is there a workaround?

Comment: There must already be a report somewhere for this.

Comment: In your fiddle, I see the same artifact in safari. screenshot: http://cl.ly/1C022t033N04190x201y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making your border transparent:

```
border: 2px solid transparent;
```

To make this work in IE6, you can add:

```
*html #inner
 {
   border-color: pink;
   filter: chroma(color=pink);
 }
```

The IE workaround is from http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/emulating-border-color-transparent-in-internet-explorer-6/

Comment: Nice, thanks! The only difference is that the border takes the same color as the inside element, not the background. Not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can solve these issues by using [`background-clip: padding-box;`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/).

It doesn't work quite perfectly on your jsfiddle example (http://jsfiddle.net/KPAVU/5/), but may have better results with the real markup.

Comment: actually; this introduced the issue for me on chrome; not a good solution anymore :)